# JavaScript, RegEx - How can I get the string that was actually found

Tags: javascript, regex, math

Why doesn't this work?

```
var str = "nd2(31)jnd";
str = str.replace(/[0-9](/,/[0-9]*(/);
```

I want to replace every number with a paranthese in front ex: "2(" with "2*("

Comment: , it doesn't work to replace ex: "2(" with "2*("

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, this does what you want:

```
str.replace(/([0-9]+)\(/g, "$1*(");
```

`$1` references the first match in parens `()`, and you have to escape `\(` to match it.

**Update:** add `g` for global matching

`2(3(4+5)) => 2*(3*(4+5))`

**Update:** Making it work on the other end of the parens too, combined:

```
str.replace(/(\d+)\(/g, "$1*(").replace(/\)(\d+)/g, ")*$1");
```

Comment: maybe more efficient is: str.replace(/([\d])\(/, "$1*(");

Comment: @Piyuesh you don't escape `(` in the pattern, you don't need square brackets around `\d` which is mostly the same as `[0-9]`

Comment: that's what i wanted!!! under the time i figured out this but with another method but your method is much more compact!:                                                                                                           http://jsbin.com/ulidab/5/

Comment: how can i do this for: )2 to )*2 ??